# Sudo pip install upgrade operation not permitted

Tags: python, numpy, pip, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Numpy on Python 2.7 on Mac El Capitan, but I keep getting errors. I have Numpy v1.8.0rc1 and I need the latest one.

`sudo pip2 install --upgrade numpy`

`...`

`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-HUSiK5-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'`

If I do
`which pip2`
I get
`/usr/local/bin/pip2`

And `which python` gives `/usr/bin/python`

Also, I installed Python 3.5, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running into System Integrity Protection, the system introduced by Apple to prevent modification of system files (see [this answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade)). Your options are approximately:

- install your own version of Python (using Homebrew or another system, e.g. `brew install python`)
- [Disable System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) (not recommended unless you know what you're doing)

Comment: I installed Homebrew and did `brew install python` and have successfully installed Python 2.7. And when I check `pip2 show numpy` it says version 1.11.1, which is what I want.

But when I actually run python and import numpy and check `np.version.version

Comment: When I check `np.version.version` it still says `'1.8.0rc1'`. Do you know why it still loads the old version?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the newer versions of Mac OS need the --user param... so try

```
sudo pip2 install --user --upgrade numpy
```